# reference render function argument in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there a way in jinja to reference the entire argument passed to the render function?

Assuming I do pass a dictionary like this

`tmplt.render({"a": 1, "b": 2}}`

is there a way to do like

```
        {% for key, value in ????.items() %}env("{{ key }}", '{{ value }}')
        {% endfor %}
```

so i do get list like

`env("a", '1')
env("b", '2')`
?

I currently solve this by using 
`tmplt.render(dic = {"a": 1, "b": 2}}` and thereafter access via `dic.items()`

```
        {% for key, value in dic.items() %}env("{{ key }}", '{{ value }}')
        {% endfor %}
```

Wondering if there is no other way so i don't have to go for dic.xxx each time?